# Open wizard on a specific step

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to open the wizard component on a specific step?

I want to open the wizard with a commandbutton.

What I have tried, it using the PrimeFaces function loadStep() to change step right after the wizard is opened, but with no luck.

For example:

```
oncomplete="PF('wizard').show();" onsuccess="PF('wiz').loadStep('step-two', true)";
```

And the other way around.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use primefaces 5 or later

```
PF('wiz').loadStep(PF('wiz').cfg.steps[0], false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is just another way of writing the same thing.
I ended up fetching the component in my Java backing, and changed the step there